# IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [myservlet] and [MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted

Tags: servlets, mapping, url-pattern

I wrote very simple dynamic web application in eclipse Mars(4.5.1) but i cannot start the tomcat server from eclipse. Below is the root cause of the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [myservlet] and [MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted
      at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:308)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2342)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2024)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1918)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1139)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
      at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
      at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
      ... 6 more
```

I followed this steps- addeding libraries in **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Libraries -> Server runtime -> Apache**. After that i added **Windows -> Preferences -> Serevr -> Runtime Environments -> Apache**. Tomcat v8.0 Server is perfectly starting from **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin **.

My **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>2J2EEProcessingFromData</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Testing</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**MyServlrt.java**

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    try{
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("pass");

        pw.write("Hello "+username);
        pw.write("Your password is:"+password);
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pw.close();
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.write("doGet called");
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.write("doPost called");
    processRequest(request, response);
}

@Override
public String getServletInfo(){
    return "Shord description";
}
```

}

Comment: That's just a summary error. The real error is in the console. Find it and copypaste it into a decent search engine to find clues and answers.

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/l/ARtvk_h9OLFGQoNqoVg9kqBtPmwOtj6W5ZA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny because i'm answering my own question i replaced url-pattern with (.java) extension as below.

```html
<url-pattern>/MyServlet.java</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on  `Servers` Tab  double-click on `Tomcat` then  change `HTTP port` in `Ports` section to any others .
or Open `Server.xml` file and change Connector Port . Restart the Server and then Check

Comment: You mean Properties -> Servers?

Comment: yes . try with that or else try with second option

Comment: The same project is working in another eclipse workspace from where i imported but it's not working in the new workspace. If the is another idea please suggest. Thankyou +1 added .

Comment: Thanks but did u try with port number i means did u try with another port number . ?

Comment: Where should i change the port number?

Comment: Go to Tomcat Folder>>Config >> Edit Server.xml   and Find for  <Connector port="XXXX" and change it to other . then restart tomcat

Comment: I guess you didn't read error log at all and also blindly focused on the summary error message which can have ANY POSSIBLE cause. The port number isn't OP's concrete problem. I copypasted the root cause from the error log straight into the question. Fix your answer accordingly.